# Add a view and display it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm totally new to MVC. Now I'm trying to create a View in the folder Sample( which is under the folder of Views). I right-clicked the Sample folder and selected "Add View", then hit the view name as *Test*. After the view has been created, I typed in following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample View</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        Test
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Build. Then I tried to navigated the address `http://localhost:24694/Sample/Test` in my browser. But the browser read "The resource cannot be found.". Why? I've also other cshtml files in the Sample folder(which was generated by others), they worked fine. For example, there is a file called "Message.cshtml" under the folder of Sample, and I can navigate the address `http://localhost:24694/Sample/Message` with ease. Is there anything that I should add?

Comment: Your working backwards here. Start with a Controller, add an action, then add a view for the action.

Comment: You need to add a method named `Test` on the `SampleController` that returns the view `return View();`. I would start by reading some documentation like [the official one](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started)

Comment: You need to have a controller called `SampleController` under Controllers folder, or configure existing controller to route to that view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot use

```
http://localhost:24694/Sample/Test
```

to navigate to view because you can only access a view through a controller. so follow these steps

1. First of all create a new controller inside controllers folder and name it 'SamplController'.
2. By default there will be an action method named Index().
3. Create a new Action method named 'Test' inside 'SampleController'
4. Now right click inside 'Test' action method and click on Add View. it will add a new view insides Views folder named 'Test.cshtml'. You can use it. if you want to place this View inside other folder then you've to modify the return statement of 'Test' action method. For example you created a folder 'MyViews' inside Views folder and moved 'Test.cshtml' there. Now your return statement in 'Test' action method will be like this

> return View("~Views/Sample/MyViews/Test.cshtml");

instead of

> return View();

Now when you use

```
http://localhost:port/Sample/Test
```

it will create a new instance of 'Sample' Controller and will call 'Test' action method. This method will return specified view. i hope it will help :)

Answer (score 2):

3 Step Process

**1 - Define the Route**

```
routes.MapRoute("Test", "test", 
                new { controller = "NameOfController", <- In your case TestController
                      action = "Index", <- Name of action in controller returning view
                      parameter = "parameterName - leave empty if no params needed"
                    });
```

**2 - Create the controller**

So if you follow the above method and call your route Test and the view Test then you need to create the controller called **TestController**. MVC automagically sows these together thanks to your route config you did earlier (RouteConfig.cs)

**3 - View**

In your case you just make sure the view is returning something.

Easy as that. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC is based on [routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx) not in file system like asp.net webforms. Following the internals, views should be in the `Views` folder from the ASP.NET MVC application template, like `Controllers` should stay on the Controllers folder. It is not required, but it is setted by default from asp.net mvc framework.

In your a `Controller` (class), you could have some `Actions` (methods), which can return a view, image, file, etc, implementations that derive from `ActionResult` type. Theses actions, could return a view using the `View` method from the controller base class. By default, the asp.net mvc will search for a view (.cshtml or .aspx file) inside the ´Views` folder and in a folder with the same name of the Controller, for sample, if you have a controller like this:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
      return View();
   }
}
```

It will find a view in `Views/Product/Index.cshtml` and render it for you. I recommend you reading more in http://asp.net/mvc

Comment: Yes, not like asp.net webforms.